# Limit 2D Array Size on the Console (C#)

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

Here's my code

```
public int[,] GetBigEyeRoad(int x)
{
   int[,] arrayBigEyeResult = new int[6, x];

   Array.Copy(arrayBigEyeRoad, arrayBigEyeResult, arrayBigEyeRoad.GetLength(0) * arrayBigEyeRoad.GetLength(1));

   return arrayBigEyeResult;
}
```

And calling it on my main class like this

```
int[,] arrayBigEyeRoad = bsb.GetBigEyeRoad(104);

    string s = "";

    for (int y = 0; y < arrayBigEyeRoad.GetLength(0); y++)
    {
        for (int x = 0; x < arrayBigEyeRoad.GetLength(1); x++)
        {
            s += string.Format("{0:D2}", arrayBigEyeRoad[y, x]);
            s += ".";
        }
        s += "\n";
    }
    Debug.Log(s);
```

Here on this part

```
int[,] arrayBigEyeRoad = bsb.GetBigEyeRoad(104);
```

I only want to display `12` 2D array values just like this

```
int[,] arrayBigEyeRoad = bsb.GetBigEyeRoad(12);
```

The problem is that it won't let me . Because it will give me an error saying

> Destination array was not long enough. Check destIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds

Now how can I possible do it something like this

[image]

Limit the 2d display on the console

Comment: and why don't you copy items one by one from one array to the other? instead of Array.Copy

Comment: @Bijan copy one by one? How can i do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
int[,] a1 = new int[100,200];
int[,] a2 = new int[10,5];

for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
        a2[i,j] = a1[i,j];
```

or

```
public class MyArray : int[,]
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        string result = "";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                result += (a1[i,j].ToString() + ",");
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: So i couldn't copy all of my elements in the a1??

Comment: As you can see on the image above is it possible that i could just hide those value or not or it this really how I should do it?

Comment: you can also override ToString

Comment: Thank you very much